# Taking derivative of the differences between elements in the matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Suppose we have $K$ matrices $X^{k}\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ for $k=1,\dots,K.$
And for each element in the matrices, denote as $x_{ij}^k$, for $i=1,\dots,p,j=1\dots,p$
.

Suppose we have an equation
$L:=\sum_{k<k'} \sum_{i,j}  |x_{ij}^k -x_{ij}^{k'}|$

and $k'$ means the $k'$-th matrix from the $K$ matrices but different to k.

Does anyone have any idea about how to derivative the equation $L$ with respect to the matrix $X^k$?

Comment: Using the element-wise `sign()` function, I think its 
$$
\def\lr#1{\left(#1\right)}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X_k}
= p\lr{\sum_{j=1}^p\,\operatorname{sign}\lr{X_k-X_j}}
$$
I'll post the details when I get more time.

Comment: @greg thanks a lot, I will try this.